# Google action required Issue found: Violation of User Data policy

Tags: firebase, google-play, crashlytics

Crossposting from [here](https://community.appinventor.mit.edu/t/google-action-required-issue-found-violation-of-user-data-policy/106987/1)

> Hello, I have received the following on 2 apps from gogIe that I build
> a while back and have no idea on how to fix it! it goes like this: We
> reviewed SDKs used by your app and found noncompliant version(s) of
> SDK(s) which collects persistent device identifiers. Persistent device
> identifiers may not be linked to other personal and sensitive user
> data or resettable device identifiers.
>
> Your app may face additional enforcement actions, if you do not
> resolve this issue by February 28, 2024 .
>
> Issue details
>
> We found an issue in the following area(s):
>
> ```
> Version code 4:
>     SDK: Fabric (Firebase Crashlytics)- ID Bridging io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric (consider upgrading to version
> ```
>
> com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.4.0)
>
> To bring your app into compliance, follow these steps :
>
> You may consider upgrading to a policy-compliant version of this SDK,
> if available from your SDK provider or removing the SDK.
>
> ```
> Fabric (Firebase Crashlytics)- ID Bridging io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric: Consider upgrading to version
> ```
>
> com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.4.0 of the SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging through our Google Play Console we found that for our own application we had an old APK marked with version 580 that was still available for older devices (API 15+).

That APK was using an old version of firebase which at the same time had the famous `io.fabric SDK` mentioned in the email from Google Play.

Removing all APK's that may include the `io.fabric` sdk thing and making a new release seems to address the issue.

Comment: How do you find it? What part of the Google Play Console do I need to look?

Comment: Go to your app, make a new release and check that in the "non included" there's the apk version that is offending the policy

Comment: Thanks, found it was a closed testing beta track app that is super old that I never replaced. I think it's dumb that a paused track can impact a production app.

Comment: Google Play never made sense and to my eyes they're bullying devs a bit too much due to their monopoly

Answer (score 0):

I released the last several updates directly without beta testing, and that seems to the be the problem. It looks like on Android you need to upload to the "Tracks" in beta to clear the old builds. So that they don't get flagged in the future for an API violation you already fixed.

I had a build in progress for the offending track, and I just submitted that to be reviewed.

1. To find the offending app APK, I clicked the link in the message "Reviewed App Bundles"
2. There I could see the version and track that was problematic.

[image: data policy violation android]

[image: Offending APK version and track to update]

I don't understand why I am forced to use the open/closed testing tracks, and maintain relevant builds there when they are paused or not used.